# I have an array where I need to get the length and it's giving me trouble

Tags: java, arrays, average

The array in the main method looks like this:

```
double[] x = { 11.11, 66.66, 88.88, 33.33, 55.55 };
```

And the code that's giving me trouble is:

```
public static double computeAverage(double[] x){

        double xTotal = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
        {
            xTotal = xTotal + x[i]; 
        }
        double computeAverage = xTotal / x.length();
        return computeAverage;
}
```

About the only thing I know for sure is that I'm trying to get the length of the array x and it's giving me an error because it's a double and not an integer. Does the "double" has an equivalent to "length" I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length()` is not a method for any array class. Instead, you should get the length through the `length` field.  Fields are accessed without parameters (i.e. without parenthesis).

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
```

Comment: Good to hear.  If you could do everyone a favor and mark the answer as accepted, that would be appreciated all-round.